# Java Stack - How do I pop() and push() multiple elements from a stack?

Tags: java, arrays, stack, push

I already have a stack class working, but right now I can only pop and push 1 element each time, I want to be able to push and pop multiple elements at the same time. without using push and pop multiple times. I'm trying to create 2 functions to do that. Functions **pushAll** and **popN**. Like:

```
public void pushAll (Object all[]) throws StackFullException {...}
public Object [] popN (int n) throws StackEmptyException {...}
```

Remarks: The input parameter all is an **array** that contains all the elements that must be entered. The last element of the vector must be on top after stacking.
If there is no space to insert all the elements, none must be inserted and a **StackFullException** exception must be raised.
The **popN** method pops the number of elements specified by the **n** parameter and deposits them into an array for return.
If the stack does not have the requested number of elements, no element is unstacked and a **StackEmptyException** exception is thrown.
I'm trying for hours to work my logic without success.
Here's my **Stack** class so far:

```
public class Stack extends RuntimeException {
    public static final int CAPACITY = 1000;
    private int capacity;
    private Object elements[];
    private int top = -1;

    public Stack(int capacity){
        if (capacity>0){
            this.capacity=capacity;
            elements=new Object[capacity];
        } else {
            this.capacity = CAPACITY;
            elements = new Object[CAPACITY];
        }
    }  
    public Stack(){
        this(CAPACITY);
    }
    
    public boolean isEmpty(){
        return (top < 0);
    }
    
    public boolean isFull(){
        return (top == capacity - 1);      
    }
    
    public void push(Object o) throws StackFullException {
        if (isFull()){
            throw new StackFullException("Stack Overflow!");
        }
        else {
            top++;
            elements[top] = o;
        }
    }
    
    public Object pop() throws StackEmptyException {
        Object elem;
        if (isEmpty()){
            throw new StackEmptyException("Stack Underflow!");
        }
        else {
            elem = elements[top];
            elements[top] = null;
            top--;
            return (elem);
        }
    }
    
    public Object top() throws StackEmptyException {
        if (isEmpty()){
            throw new StackEmptyException("Stack Underflow!");
        }
        else {
            return (elements[top]);
        }
    }
    
    public int size(){
        return (top + 1);
    };

    public Object[] getElements() {
        return elements;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        String string = "[";
        for (int i = 0; i < this.capacity; i++){
            Object element = this.elements[i];
            
            if(element != null){
                string += element + ",";
            }
        }
        string =  string.substring(0, string.length() - 1);
        string += "]";
        return string;
    }
    
    
    public void pushAll (Object all[]) throws StackFullException {
    
    }
    public Object [] popN (int n) throws StackEmptyException {
        
    }
}
```

Could help me build the pushAll and popN functions?

Comment: I suggest that you show what you've tried.

Comment: It’s impossible. Computers operate sequentially or in parallel but then you would run into race conditions along with other weird shit. I don’t even think in quant computers it’s possible but then again I don’t know too much about that.

Comment: Did you _really_ mean to write `Stack extends RuntimeException`?  That seems slightly odd to me.

Answer (score -1):

There is no such way. You can push and pop only one element at a time. What you can do is make a method, pass down the stack and number of the elements you want to pop or push, and achieve it using loop.